# Array of Class Module type not updating

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, vb6

I've struck my foot against some weird arrays, to which i can assign value to the whole array but not individual array members.

This is a data class module, named Class_E

```
    Public Name As Variant
    Public Age As Variant
```

and this is the body code, which just assigns and re-assigns values to 2 arrays

```
Sub main()
    Dim r As Class_E
    Set r = Band()
End Sub

Function Band() As Class_E
    Set Band = New Class_E

    'Part 1: Initialize the variables
    Debug.Print "Part 1"
    Band.Name = Array("Edison", "Tesla", "Faraday", "Turing")
    Debug.Print "Before: Name={" & Band.Name(0) & ", " & Band.Name(1) & ", " & Band.Name(2) & ", " & Band.Name(3) & "}"
    Band.Age = Array(10, 10, 10, 10)
    Debug.Print "Before: Age={" & Band.Age(0) & ", " & Band.Age(1) & ", " & Band.Age(2) & ", " & Band.Age(3) & "}"

    'Part 2: Change values of arrays, by item
    Debug.Print "Part 2"
    For k = LBound(Band.Name) To UBound(Band.Name)
        Debug.Print "k=" & k
        Band.Name(k) = "Foo"
        Band.Age(k) = 999
    Next k
    Debug.Print "After: Name={" & Band.Name(0) & ", " & Band.Name(1) & ", " & Band.Name(2) & ", " & Band.Name(3) & "}"
    Debug.Print "After: Age={" & Band.Age(0) & " " & Band.Age(1) & " " & Band.Age(2) & " " & Band.Age(3) & "}"

    'Part 3: Change values of array, entirely
    Debug.Print "Part 3"
    Band.Name = Array("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter")
    Debug.Print "Again: Name={" & Band.Name(0) & ", " & Band.Name(1) & ", " & Band.Name(2) & ", " & Band.Name(3) & "}"
    Band.Age = Array(11, 11, 11, 11)
    Debug.Print "Again: Age={" & Band.Age(0) & ", " & Band.Age(1) & ", " & Band.Age(2) & ", " & Band.Age(3) & "}"

    'Part 4: Use another temp array variable
    Debug.Print "Part 4"
    Dim Temp_Name As Variant, Temp_Age As Variant
    Temp_Name = Band.Name
    Temp_Age = Band.Age
    For k = LBound(Band.Name) To UBound(Band.Name)
        Debug.Print "k=" & k
        Temp_Name(k) = "Foo"
        Temp_Age(k) = 999
    Next k
    Debug.Print "Temp: Name={" & Temp_Name(0) & ", " & Temp_Name(1) & ", " & Temp_Name(2) & ", " & Temp_Name(3) & "}"
    Debug.Print "Temp: Age={" & Temp_Age(0) & " " & Temp_Age(1) & " " & Temp_Age(2) & " " & Temp_Age(3) & "}"

    'Part 5: Original arrays again
    Debug.Print "Part 5"
    Debug.Print "Again: Name={" & Band.Name(0) & ", " & Band.Name(1) & ", " & Band.Name(2) & ", " & Band.Name(3) & "}"
    Debug.Print "Again: Age={" & Band.Age(0) & ", " & Band.Age(1) & ", " & Band.Age(2) & ", " & Band.Age(3) & "}"

End Function
```

This is the output screen I've got

```
Part 1
Before: Name={Edison, Tesla, Faraday, Turing}
Before: Age={10, 10, 10, 10}
Part 2
k=0
k=1
k=2
k=3
After: Name={Edison, Tesla, Faraday, Turing}
After: Age={10 10 10 10}
Part 3
Again: Name={Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter}
Again: Age={11, 11, 11, 11}
Part 4
k=0
k=1
k=2
k=3
Temp: Name={Foo, Foo, Foo, Foo}
Temp: Age={999 999 999 999}
Part 5
Again: Name={Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter}
Again: Age={11, 11, 11, 11}
```

Questions:

1. Why are the simple assignments in Part 2 not executed ? and there is no error message. we have no problem re-assigning the arrays as shown in Part 3.

2. Why "Temp_Name = Band.Name" in Part 4 a copy of array values instead of the array pointer ? There is no instruction for memory allocation to the temporary arrays.

Your inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: You should be working with `Band(0 to 3)`, not `Band.Name(0 to 3)`. Looping thrtough would be `Band(k).Name = "Foo"`.

Comment: Using arrays as class members is problematic. Use collections or dictionaries instead. You can also envisage a better design scheme like suggested by @Jeeped. Besides, `Name` is a keyword in VBA, don't use it for your variables.

Comment: @Jeeped, In fact, this is an isolated problem from a larger project. I need an array as part of the class structure so can't do Band(0 to 3).

Comment: @A.S.H. we can change Name to other thing but the problem remains

Comment: for arrays, use a type (udt). So you wont be stuck with using variants who are confusing. For class type, i recommend dictionaries, more flexible than collections.

Answer (score 3):

Using arrays as public class members is problematic. There's a reason why VBA does not allow it. You tried to overcome this restriction by declaring the members as `Variant`, but this does not solve the problem.

You can possibly use `Collection`s or `Dictionary`s, because these are `Objects` so you can `Set` **references** on them. But VBA Arrays are *Value-types*. Hence when you get an array from a function, you will get a **copy** of the array.

> 1. Why are the simple assignments in Part 2 not executed ? and there is no error message. we have no problem re-assigning the arrays as shown in Part 3.

Because you actually worked on a *copy* of the array. In the statement

> ```
> Band.Name(k) = "Foo"
> ```

Although `Band.Name` seems to access directly a field of the class, it is actually accessing it through a property get "wrapper"; this is always the case with public class members, the compiler automatically adds get/let wrappers needed for COM's IDispatch interface and eventual late-binding (accessing the class in an `object` reference). The wrapper returns a **copy** of the array, **not a reference**, because as stated earlier, Arrays in VBA (and Strings for that matter) are *value-types*, not objects. So yoiu worked on the copy of the array.

You can overcome this problem by adding `Property Let` methods that assign entries in the member array. Consider this code for your class:

```
Public Names As Variant '<-- Change to plural to add property get/let
Public Ages As Variant  ' <-- Same

Public Property Let Name(i As Long, s As String)
  Names(i) = s
End Property

Public Property Let Age(i As Long, val As Long)
  Ages(i) = val
End Property
```

You can use these to assign entries in the member arrays. Your Part2 will then work as expected.

> 2. Why "Temp_Name = Band.Name" in Part 4 a copy of array values instead of the array pointer? There is no instruction for memory allocation to the temporary arrays.

As stated earlier, arrays are value-types, not objects. Assigning an array to a variable always creates a *copy*, never a *duplicate reference* like the object case. (add to that the wrapper property get and you find yourself two miles away from the initial class's array).

Comment: @Jeeped thanks. Your suggested design change is good as well, but I wrote this when OP insisted the class has to have those "array members" for some reason...

Comment: wouldn't it still work as a public array class, even if in this code `names` and `ages` are declared as private and have a type other than variant (for example `private names() as Long`), and keep the properties as is ?

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier it is always better to make members private and provide access properties. In reality (as I mention in the answer) public members are no more than private members with compiler generated access properties. The crux of the problem is that in any case, you will not get a reference on the member array, but a copy (unless using some pointer hacks/tricks).

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with my recommendation to flip how you are storing the arrays from Band.Name(0 to 3) to Band(0 to 3).Name, here is some working code.

**Class_E (Code) Class Module code sheet**

```
Option Explicit

Private pName As String
Private pAge As Long

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Age() As Long
    Age = pAge
End Property
Public Property Let Age(Value As Long)
    pAge = Value
End Property
```

**Standard Module1 (Code) code sheet**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim i As Long, r() As New Class_E
    r = fillBand()
    For i = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
        Debug.Print r(i).Name & " - " & r(i).Age
    Next i
End Sub

Function fillBand() As Class_E()
    Dim tmpBands() As New Class_E, tmp1 As Variant, tmp2 As Variant, i As Long

    'Part 1: Initialize the variables
    Debug.Print "Part 1"
    tmp1 = Array("Edison", "Tesla", "Faraday", "Turing")
    tmp2 = Array(5, 10, 15, 20)
    ReDim tmpBands(LBound(tmp1) To UBound(tmp1))

    For i = LBound(tmp1) To UBound(tmp1)
        With tmpBands(i)
            .Name = tmp1(i)
            .Age = tmp2(i)
        End With
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Before: Name={" & tmpBands(0).Name & ", " & tmpBands(1).Name & ", " & tmpBands(2).Name & ", " & tmpBands(3).Name & "}"
    Debug.Print "Before: Age={" & tmpBands(0).Age & ", " & tmpBands(1).Age & ", " & tmpBands(2).Age & ", " & tmpBands(3).Age & "}"

    'Part 2: Initialize the variables
    Debug.Print "Part 2"
    tmp1 = Array("foo", "bar", "foobar", "else")
    tmp2 = Array(9, 99, 999, 9999)
    ReDim tmpBands(LBound(tmp1) To UBound(tmp1))

    For i = LBound(tmp1) To UBound(tmp1)
        tmpBands(i).Name = tmp1(i)
        tmpBands(i).Age = tmp2(i)
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Before: Name={" & tmpBands(0).Name & ", " & tmpBands(1).Name & ", " & tmpBands(2).Name & ", " & tmpBands(3).Name & "}"
    Debug.Print "Before: Age={" & tmpBands(0).Age & ", " & tmpBands(1).Age & ", " & tmpBands(2).Age & ", " & tmpBands(3).Age & "}"

    'Part 3: Initialize the variables
    Debug.Print "Part 3"
    tmp1 = Array("spring", "summer", "fall", "winter")
    tmp2 = Array(1, 11, 111, 1111)
    ReDim tmpBands(LBound(tmp1) To UBound(tmp1))

    For i = LBound(tmp1) To UBound(tmp1)
        tmpBands(i).Name = tmp1(i)
        tmpBands(i).Age = tmp2(i)
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Before: Name={" & tmpBands(0).Name & ", " & tmpBands(1).Name & ", " & tmpBands(2).Name & ", " & tmpBands(3).Name & "}"
    Debug.Print "Before: Age={" & tmpBands(0).Age & ", " & tmpBands(1).Age & ", " & tmpBands(2).Age & ", " & tmpBands(3).Age & "}"

    fillBand = tmpBands
End Function
```

**Results from Immediate Window**

```
Part 1
Before: Name={Edison, Tesla, Faraday, Turing}
Before: Age={5, 10, 15, 20}
Part 2
Before: Name={foo, bar, foobar, else}
Before: Age={9, 99, 999, 9999}
Part 3
Before: Name={spring, summer, fall, winter}
Before: Age={1, 11, 111, 1111}
Returned Values:
spring - 1
summer - 11
fall - 111
winter - 1111
```

Comment: Nice modification. Unfortunately i have arrays of different sizes so have to leave them as arrays in objects rather than converting to arrays of objects.